# TestNG command line not working (java org.testng.TestNG )

Tags: java, testng

i'm trying to run testng tests using command line like this :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\automatic tests testNG>java -cp
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.3.1\
 testng-6.3.1.jar org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

but i'm getting this error :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: and
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   Could not find the main class: and.  Program will exit.
```

So How to add testNG to the classpath.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The spaces in the filename are confusing things - Java thinks that only the `c:\Documents` part is in the classpath argument. Try this:

```
java -cp
   "C:\Documents and Settings"\Administrateur\.m2\repository\org\
   testng\testng\6.3.1\testng-6.3.1.jar org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

(where the whole thing is on one line and there's no break after "org" of course)

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work so i tried this 
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\Bureau\automatic tests testNG>java -cp
testng-6.3.1.jar org.testng.TestNG testng.xml but the problem persits :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run via java on command line, you'll need to either enquote your path (`"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrateur\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.3.1\"`) or alter slightly as follows: `C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Administrateur\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.3.1\`.  You may also want to run via maven to avoid having to specify this classpath info.